# flatten an array of arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, nested, integer

how to write a code snippet Ruby that will flatten an array of arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers. e.g. [[1,2,[3]],4] -> [1,2,3,4]. Please don't use any built-in flatten functions in either language.

Comment: By "either language," what other language do you imply?

Comment: Why do you need to do so?

Comment: You should put bounty on such questions where contribution from your end is only the specification of the problem.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. We expect to see your effort toward solving the problem since SO isn't a "write code for me" site. Instead we help you fix the code you wrote. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 and

Answer (score 6):

Here's one solution without using the built-in `flatten` method. It involves recursion

```
def flattify(array)
  array.each_with_object([]) do |element, flattened|
    flattened.push *(element.is_a?(Array) ? flattify(element) : element)
  end
end
```

I tested this out in irb.

```
flattify([[1,2,[3],4])
=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answer is wrong? I tested it myself in irb. You can too

Comment: But I realized that the elements will only be integers.

Comment: Is there an example test case where this method fails? If so, I want to test it out?

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [[1,2,[3]],4]
```

If, as in you example, `arr` contains only numbers, you could (as opposed to "should") do this:

```
eval "[#{arr.to_s.delete('[]')}]"
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Ewww! Props for creativity, but... Ewwww! :D

Comment: Quite Clever but I wouldn't use it.